# how to use UISwipeGestureRecognizer in the project created by cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uiswipegesturerecognizer

i created a project by using cocos2d,and now i want to use UISwipeGestureRecognizer for get the up/down/left/right, so how can i do?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the .h file add this :

```
// Add inside @interface
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * _swipeLeftRecognizer;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * _swipeRightRecognizer;

// Add after @interface
@property (retain) UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeLeftRecognizer;
@property (retain) UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeRightRecognizer;
```

In .m file add this :

```
// Add after @implementation
@synthesize swipeLeftRecognizer = _swipeLeftRecognizer;
@synthesize swipeRightRecognizer = _swipeRightRecognizer;

// Then add these new methods
- (void)onEnter {
    self.swipeLeftRecognizer = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSwipe:)] autorelease];
    _swipeLeftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:_swipeLeftRecognizer];    

    self.swipeRightRecognizer = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightSwipe:)] autorelease];
    _swipeRightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addGestureRecognizer:_swipeRightRecognizer];    
}

- (void)onExit {
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] removeGestureRecognizer:_swipeLeftRecognizer];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] removeGestureRecognizer:_swipeRightRecognizer];
}

// Add to dealloc
_swipeLeftRecognizer = nil;
[_swipeRightRecognizer release];
_swipeRightRecognizer = nil;
```

Hope it'll help